# Speech Recogniser Intent not getting back the data in OnActivityResult

Tags: android

I have an Speech Recognizer Intent on click of a button.

```
voiceSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Now...");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v("Speech", "Could not find any Speech Recognition Actions");
        }

    }
});
```

On Activity Result I have the code as

```
     @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     System.out.println("Request code++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+requestCode);
     System.out.println("Result Code+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+resultCode);
     System.out.println("Data++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+data);
   System.out.println("Language"+data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE));
     System.out.println("data.getDataString()"+data.getDataString());
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            String searchKey = data.getData().toString(); 
            System.out.println("Search Key++++++++++++++++++++++++"+searchKey);
            searchEditText.setText(searchKey);
            webView.loadUrl(url+"searchKey");

        }
 }
 }
```

The output I get is when I am printing in `onActivityResult` is

Request Code I get as `1`

Result Code I get as `-1`

Data I get as `Intent { (has extras) }`

Language `data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE)` as `null`.

`Data.getDataString()` as `null`.

Could anybody let me know what could be wrong I might be making in the code.

thanks.

Comment: Your variable `REQUEST_CODE` is equal to `1`, right? Otherwise this is a result from another Activity.

Comment: @Hbcdev yes my REQUEST_CODE is equal to `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trying to get at the results in the wrong way. They're not stored in the data string, but in a matches array.

You can get the array by doing:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

Each entry in the array will be a multi-word string representing one guess the recogniser has for what the user said.

Comment: the result code I get as `-1`, then `if` statement does not gets executed at all, so how could I get data if it does not executes code in `if` statement. thanks.

Comment: thanks got it to work perfectly, but `onActivityResult` I could not make an `webView` to load the url, getting as Requested Web Service Unavailable. But I can get through to load url and see the same result in browser.

Comment: This sounds like a new problem -- I suggest making a new question for it.